# Get String from NSMutableString in swift

Tags: swift, string, nsmutablestring

What's the proper way of getting a `String` from a `NSMutableString`? I am currently using:

```
var mutableString = NSMutableString(string: string)
var string = mutableString.substring(from: 0)
```

which seems a bit hackish...

Thanks

Comment: Your code is not very meaningful. Looking at the code *the proper way* is **not** to use `NSMutableString` at all.

Comment: You can bridge cast between them: `var string = mutableString as String`

Comment: @vadian I have skipped the part where I modified the string as this was not important for my question. Here it is: mutableString.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 4, length: 5), with: "XXXXX")

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the `NSMutableString` as `String`:

```
var mutableString = NSMutableString(string: "Example")
var string = String(mutableString)
```

Or:

```
var mutableString = NSMutableString(string: "Example")
var string = mutableString as String
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments *the proper way is **not** to use `NSMutableString` at all*.

Your given example

```
let mutableString = NSMutableString(string: "Hello World")
mutableString.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 4, length: 5), with: "XXXXX")
let swiftString = String(mutableString)
```

can be written in native Swift

```
var string = "Hello World"

let nsRange = NSRange(location: 4, length: 5)
string.replaceSubrange(Range(nsRange, in: string)!, with: "XXXXX")
```

Same result but the latter is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let newStr = String(mutableString)
```